# Find the sum of the elements from the beginning of an array to the first negative number

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, frontend

I need to find the sum of elements from the beginning of the array to the first negative number, using loops, like "for". I want loop to summarize all the elements of array before the first negative number and return the sum.

Like for example if I have:

> arr = [1, 2, 3, -4, 5]

I need to summarize all elements before "-4" , output would be

> 6

to print in the console.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Simply iterate over the numbers and break the loop at the first negative one.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, -4, 5];
let res = 0;
for (const num of arr) {
  if (num < 0) break;
  res += num;
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Logic is clear. but I am not sure how to make it simple.
To be honest, for loop takes long time than map or reduce.